# Where are the OS specific properties located used by virt-install --os-variant

Tags: kvm-virtualization, libvirt, qemu, virsh, virt-install

Using

```
virt-install ... --os-variant win10 ...
```

`virt-install` create a new VM optimized for Windows 10.

But where are those OS specific properties located?
E.g. `machine-type` and the `<hyperv>` elements (the one specified in the virt XML)

Been looking in the osinfo-db XML files, but they don't seem to hold the informations.
Or are they simply hard-coded in the `virt-install` binaries?
If so, how can I determine which OSs my current `virt-install` version support?

I'm aware of `osinfo-query` for finding the OS name, but `virt-install` need to know the OS optimized properties from somewhere, right?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, those elements are hardcoded into virt-install source.

libosinfo mostly gives the default hardware devices, and automated installers execution, and some defaults for memory/cpu/disk settings.

Comment: But would it do me any good to update the osinfo-db in relation to virt-inst?
E.g. Debian Buster "stock" installation doesn't include Win Srv 2019, but it is included in the newest [osinfo-db](https://releases.pagure.org/libosinfo/osinfo-db-20200325.tar.xz) from pagure.org. I took a quick look in the XMLs and it doesn't seem to include the information needed to construct and OS optimized VM.

Comment: You can easily update your osinfo-db dataset locally, using the `osinfo-db-import` command.  NB if you're running `virt-install` as root, then you'll need to run `osinfo-db-import` as root too.

Comment: I know, but as far I can tell, it will not do you any good in relation to `virt-install`. It will not update `virt-install`